# .htaccess Redirect link combination

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hyperlink, combinations

I have the following code in my htaccess file:

```
Redirect /produkte/category/subcategory/ https://www.newsite.com/category/subcategory
Redirect /produkte/category/subcategory/product/ https://www.newsite.com/category/product
```

the first line works ok, but the second line is redirected to combination of lines:

```
https://www.newsite.com/category/subcategoryproduct
```

this example is one of the simple ones, but there is some more complicated links, how can I make each of line considered separately from the previous lines?

Comment: Sounds like newsite has its own redirection rules interpreting "subcategory" as a product...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all,
solved with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^/produkte/category/subcategory/$ https://www.newsite.com/category/subcategory? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^/produkte/category/subcategory/product/$ https://www.newsite.com/category/product? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```